# jax-rs web service: how to hide some entity fields and use SSL

Tags: ssl, jaxb, jax-rs

Recently I asked some questions here about web services

[How to secure a database using web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783785/how-to-secure-a-database-using-web-services)

[Glassfish: deploy of multiple applications, some of them with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898888/glassfish-deploy-of-multiple-applications-some-of-them-with-ssl)

but didn't find answers at all
This time I will try to be more specific hoping to find some help...

I created a simple web service in Netbeans using the wizard which creates a web service from a Database table. The wizard creates a persistence unit, entity classes and uses JPA.
The restful web service is created using jax-rs and I checked "Use Jersey default" which caused the creation of a web.xml file.
It works but in the database table there are some fields I need for filtering but I don't want reported to the client: how can I hide them in the xml/json produced by the restful web service ?

How can I force to use SSL ?

I tried to put

```
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

in web.xml, it forces SSL but the response is not the same, it is not xml/json but it contains only the concatenation of the values of the entities ' fields. Besides some URI  with path parameters don't work at all. What am I missing ?

Thanks
Filippo

**Update about SSL**

I made some more checks and using Firefox I got valid responses using SSL, while I get weird results with IE9. In that case forcing to use SSL I got a single long string with alphanumeric characters. As soon as possible I'm going to repeat the test on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Jersey you should have Jackson along with that. Jackson helps working with entity -> JSON and JSON -> entity parsing.

You're looking for an annotation called

```
@JsonIgnore
```

And you'll want to put that on the 'getter' method of the member you wish to obscure from the output.

Source: http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: In the Jersey implementation which comes with Netbeans 7.3 it seems Jackson is not included because the annotation above is not recognized. I ended using the old sweet @XmlTransient annotation combined with @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD).