# Is there a way to persist a field but when performing a GET the field isn't serialized

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jax-rs, quarkus

So, I want to persist a user with `password` field, but with the return I don't want to show
the `password`. Somehow I just want to serialize the field to persist, but on a `findById(id)`
or `findAll()` this field must not be shown.
The fields that the user will fill:

```
{
    "firstName" : "foo",
    "lastName" : "bar",
    "password" : "MyNewPass",
    "email": "john@doe.net"
}
```

The data I'll persist:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName" : "foo",
    "lastName" : "bar",
    "email": "john@doe.net",
    "password" : "$2y$12$0bpN8aTD5WebsGWoXK90yuJcDczNmUIAOduWXoHKfEw7GOidpQX1u",
    "createdDate": "01/01/2077",
    "active": "false"
}
```

What I want the user (frontend) to see as a response:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName" : "foo",
    "lastName" : "bar",
    "email": "john@doe.net",
    "active": "false"
}
```

If I remove the `getPassword()` I won't be able to validate a login session, since I need internally check the password hash. I'm able to create 3 different Classes but there will be a lot of duplicated code.

There's a better approach to this kind of situation? Inheritance? Some kind of annotation? An interface? I'm losing something?

The currently Repo I'm working on: [customer-service](https://github.com/JohnneSouza/quarkus-easy-ecom/tree/main/customer-service)

Comment: Can you show the class def for the object? What library are you using to serialize it?

Comment: I'm using JAX-RS and the Class Def is the middle one the data I persist, currently I'm manually setting the fields that I don't want to show, to null where they are called.

Comment: Does [@JsonIgnore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965504/jax-rs-web-service-how-to-hide-some-entity-fields-and-use-ssl) work?

Comment: It does, but when I need to retrieve the user's info from the database the field `password` is ignored, so I cant compare with the user's input to check if he entered a valid password.

Comment: not so. @JsonIgnore only affects *rendering to json*, and my guess is you are looking at the object as json Hibernate ignores the annotation and populates the field just like any other. See for yourself with `System.out.println(user.getPassword())`

Comment: @Bohemian Well, that's embarrassing you're right, I was looking after the JSON output and not the object itself. That solved 100% my problem, if you want to post this comment as a answer I would gladly accept as the correct one! Thanks!

Comment: In that case, it's dupe! Closing now...

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an entity that looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private LocalDate createdDate;
    private String email;
    private boolean active;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

You could map this entity to a User class that is specifically for web requests:

```
public class UserResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private boolean active;
}
```

You can map the User to UserResponse manually or use a mapping framework like MapStruct.

This is much cleaner than adding an annotation that might do the work for you. The Entity class should be used for persistence and should not be tainted with additional responsibilities.

Comment: Currently I've 3 Classes, `UserDTO`, `UserResponse` and `UserRegisterRequest`, I'm able to keep the desired behavior with these 3 Classes, but you see, they share more than half of the atributes with each one, what I want is just to 'Clean my code' from duplicated content. I added the repo I'm working on in the main tread if you wanna check.

Comment: @JohnnesSouza removing identical pieces is not the same as "cleaning the code". Often it's quite the opposite - namely when it ties evolution of one object to evolution of another. If you remove duplicated code and arrive in place where changes to your database spill over to your REST api, then the removal makes the code dirtier, not cleaner. Which might be a good trade-off (sometimes we prefer "short" to "clean"), but it's important to understand that it's a trade-off, not a good practice.

Comment: @fdreger I'm quite aware about the Clean code idea, and I know that it isn't about removing code, I just expressed myself in the wrong way. The main ideia of the refactoring is to remove duplicated code is to fully use the OOP structure to provide a better code. I can achieve the desired behavior in N manners, but Keeping It Simple isn't as easy as it should be ;/. Anyway, thanks for the shoutout.

Comment: @JohnnesSouza you could solve your 'problem' by annotating the String password field with @ JsonIgnore... but I totally agree with fdreger that this is bad practice and I would strongly advice against using it. Having seen your code I have two things to consider: 1. Separation of concerns (don't let your application model also be an entity and a DTO for example) and 2. Try to use some of the Quarkus goodness... you're mostly using Spring and the patterns that come with it. Quarkus really has some nice frameworks that can help you along the way.

Comment: Yeap, I tried using @JsonIgnore and 
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY), but I'm not able to retrieve the password field in any of these methods, I also tried to anotate the Getter and Setter methods, but the field just doesn't want to behave correcly. What I could do is just a method do retrieve the password from the db based on the email provided and compares the Hashes. This way I would only have 2 Classes one DTO and a model.

Comment: Why don't you use Quarkus security jpa to do the security stuff for you? In that way you won't have to worry so much about the password.

Comment: You're absolutely right Robert, I couldn't agree more, but I'm coming from a Spring environment and this project is a way for me to learn more about this new stack/framework. That's one of the reasons I'm using spring-jpa as a dependency.

Comment: I know it is tempting to stick with the ways we are used to. If you go with the standard Quarkus stuff, you will get a lot of Quarkus goodness out of the box. I have to admit it was a steep learning curve for me as well, but it was worth it. (And no, not everything in Quarkus is better, but it helps to stick to their standards.)